# How to programmatically generate React Bootstrap Cards based on data from fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to programmatically generate React Bootstrap cards based on the results from a fetch. I have done this before using html tables instead of Bootstrap cards and I was hoping that the same approach would work but it does not because I keep receiving the following error: 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. So I guess React Bootstrap elements don't function the same way as HTML elements. How would I go about doing this? My old code using HTML tables is below, hopefully there is a way to do this because I have been working for hours to no avail.

```
let body = document.getElementById("tableBody");
                    let tableRow = body.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
                    //set the id of the row to the track id
                    tableRow.id = data[i].id;
                    let row = body.lastChild;
                    //create a td for the title
                    row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
                    row.lastChild.innerHTML = data[i].title;
                    //create a td for the artist
                    row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
                    row.lastChild.innerHTML = data[i].artist;
                    //create a td for the year
                    row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
                    row.lastChild.innerHTML = data[i].year;
                    //create a td for the genre
                    row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
                    row.lastChild.innerHTML = data[i].genre;
                    //create a td for the tags
                    row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
                    row.lastChild.innerHTML = data[i].tags;
                    //create a td for the url
                    row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
                    row.lastChild.innerHTML = data[i].url;
```

In addition, I am using Bootstrap Containers, Rows, and Cols, to orient my cards in a grid fashion.

Comment: And my code was in a for loop that looped through the data returned from the fetch

Comment: you don't create React elements by appending html with javascript like that. You can create bootstrap elements like that, but they'll have nothing to do with React. React has its own way of generating elements. Are you working inside the context of a react project?